# Spark-Scala connection

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Have a case of connecting to Spark using Scala. Previously I didn't have experience with Scala and used Python in combination with Spark.

So for Python the connection was done like this:

```
import findspark
import pyspark
findspark.init('/Users/SD/Data/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="myAppName")
```

and then the coding process began.

So my question is- how can I establish the connection to Spark using Scala dialect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irrespective of python or scala, the following steps are common

1. Make the jars available to the language you are using (python path for python and sbt entry for scala)

scala

```
name := "ProjectName" 
version := "1.0" 
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.0"
```

python

```
PYTHONPATH=/Users/XXX/softwares/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python:/Users/XXX/softwares/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:PYTHONPATH
```

2. Once the libraries are available, the usage is regular as below

In scala

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
new SparkContext(conf)
```

In python

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

the code snippet you provided is getting the libraries for python. It may work, but might not the final approach you would follow.